# teleoperation using custom key

Tags: ros, navigation, teleop, teleoperation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

so far we are moving out P3AT (spawned in USARSim) from my ROS machine using teleoperation.
The difficulty we are observing is,
-using default teleoperation key is not comfortable to operate the robot.
**-we want to drive it using arrow key given on keyboard** (which is also used by most of the computer games).
does ROS provide this facility. Or what next we should do.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204958/teleoperation-using-custom-key/) by [sumant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20291/sumant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2015-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can also use this node, which has a slightly different keys. http://wiki.ros.org/teleop_twist_keyboard

There's also this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/joy/Tutorials/WritingTeleopNode

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0